# Stripe Subscription with Payment Method

Tags: php, swift, stripe-payments

I'm using the latest version of iOS Stripe SDK (1.27), where the `STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate` instead of returning a `STPToken`, now returns a `PaymentMethod` object.

```
func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in
       // Send the paymentMethod.stripeId to my Server
   })
}
```

On the server side, I verified if the user on my system already has a customer object and create or update accordingly the Customer, like:

```
Customer::create(['email'=> email, 'payment_method' => payment_method_id])
```

But after trying to create a subscription, with the following piece of code:

```
Subscription::create(['customer' => customer, 'plan' => plan_id])
```

It returns the following error:

> This customer has no attached payment source

Note: As a workaround I can return to the previous version of the iOS SDK when STPToken was generated and use as source (in that way was working). But I want to use the new PaymentMethod API.

1. Is there a way to convert a PaymentMethod to a token? (or is it correct to send to server the PaymentMethod.stripeId)?
2. What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that can help you. I had the same issue and solved it. You can use this code :

```
Subscription::create([
  'customer' => $customer,
  'plan' => $plan_id,
  'default_payment_method' => $paymentMethodId
]);
```

or

> To use this PaymentMethod as the default for invoice or subscription
>   payments, set invoice_settings.default_payment_method, on the Customer
>   to the PaymentMethod’s ID.

```
Customer::create([
'email'=> email,
'payment_method' => $paymentMethodId
'invoice_settings' => ['default_payment_method' => $paymentMethodId]
])
```

Comment: Thank you @ Spawnrad for you response. I'll test and let you know.

Comment: How do you get $paymentMethodId value? `STPPaymentMethod` does not have this property.

Comment: @elbertrivas hi elbert, Here how you get the payment method id : https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object
For me i get that after submit the card number in my form. When i add card or make a payment. Hope that can help you.

Comment: Are you using Stripe prebuilt card controller? In my case, I'm using STPPaymentCardTextField.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to solve it. Thanks anyway man.